# two paginations in a single page

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I use the normal pagination method in wordpress

```
<?php $i = 1 ?>
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('posts_per_page' => "2", 'paged' => $paged, 'cat' => 26 );
query_posts($args);
?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 
<div class="art_1">

    <h5><?php echo $i ?>.   <?php the_title(); ?></h5>
<?php $i++; ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>


<div class="er">
<?php next_posts_link(); ?>
</div>
<div class="err">
<?php previous_posts_link(); ?>
```

It works fine but the problem is this pagination I use for listing out articles in a particular category ,now I have another category of articles in same page which needs pagination too.pagination of 1st should no affect the other and vice versa. Can anyone suggest me what should I do?

Comment: two pagination on one page?

Comment: i am not exp in word-press, but if its custom php, you have to do Ajax call for pagination and change the data in their specific divs.
right now you are doing pagination  through URL so of course it will effect both pagination

Answer (score 0):

Use this hook after pagination..

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```